# How can I code my while loop to check 2 separate user inputs?

Tags: python

Python beginner here, sorry if this is an easy question!

I already have a working while loop

```py
while True:
    do_youwanttoplay = input("Do you want to play? ").lower() 

    if do_youwanttoplay == "yes": 
        print ("You are starting with", health, "health")
        print ("Let's play!")
        break
    elif do_youwanttoplay == "no":
        print ("Cya...")
        break
    else:
        print ("Please enter either yes or no")
```

but with this next block of code I would like it to check if the user has typed 'yes or 'no(which it currently does) and also check if the user types 'across' or 'around

```
 while True:    
    first_choice = input("First choice... Left or Right (left/right)? ").lower() 

    if first_choice == "left":
            ans = input("Nice, you follow the path and reach a lake...Do you swim across or go around (across/around)? ")
            break
    elif first_choice == "right":
            print("test")
    else:
        print ("Please enter either left or right")          


    if ans == "across":
                print ("You managed to get across, but were bit by a fish and lost 5 health")
                health -= 5
                print ("Your health is now", health)
    elif ans == "around": 
                print ("You went around and avoided getting bit by the fish, well done!")
```

Comment: Great to see you learning Python! This really isn’t the right sort of question for this site though. You’ll get a much better reception if you ask a specific technical question, so instead of “how do I make my program do X?”, asking something like “how do I create a dictionary with default values?”.

Comment: Btw have you tried to tackle the problem you’re asking about? Why not play around with Python and see if you can get it working on your own? No snark intended, it’s a great way to learn.

Comment: I have been trying for a good few hours Bob :D I even resulted to asking chatGPT to help, which has been amazing with every question, except this one! I have a feeling I can maybe nest another loop inside that code of block and that might work, but it's really over my head. I have written 117 lines of code, enemys have health, I have an attacking loop which deducts health, pick up items, inventory etc, but this has really got me.

Comment: Keep trying at it, and like I said if you have a specific technology question definitely ask it here. But these types of questions usually get downvoted pretty quickly as they’re off topic for this site.

Comment: Also if you’re in over your head, maybe try something simpler and build up the complexity of your programs more gradually.

Comment: "but with this next block of code I would like it to check if the user has typed 'yes or 'no(which it currently does) and also check if the user types 'across' or 'around" - **what happens** when you try the existing code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of how you organize the while loops.

I was able to get the following to work, in a manner that I believe is how you wanted it.

I added a `stop` boolean to determine if the main loop should be exited or not.

```py
health = 150
stop = False
while not stop:
    while True:
        do_youwanttoplay = input("Do you want to play? ").lower()
        if do_youwanttoplay == "yes":
            print("You are starting with", health, "health")
            print("Let's play!")
            break;
        elif do_youwanttoplay == "no":
            print("Cya...")
            stop = True
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either yes or no")

    if stop:
        break

    while True:
        first_choice = input("First choice... Left or Right (left/right)? ").lower()
        if first_choice == "left":
            print("Nice, you follow the path and reach a lake...")
            ans = input("Do you swim across or go around (across/around)? ")
            if ans == "across":
                print("You managed to get across, but were bit by a fish and lost 5 health")
                health -= 5
                print("Your health is now", health)
            elif ans == "around":
                print("You went around and avoided getting bit by the fish, well done!")
        elif first_choice == "right":
            print("test")
        else:
            print("Please enter either left or right")
```